# How to make python .post() requests to retry?

Tags: python, python-requests, urllib3

I'm trying to implement requests retry in Python.
It works like charm with `.get()` requests, but a `.post()` request never retries, regardless of a status code. I'd like to use it with `.post()` requests.

My code:

```
from requests.packages.urllib3.util import Retry
from requests.adapters import HTTPAdapter
from requests import Session, exceptions

s = Session()
s.mount('http://', HTTPAdapter(max_retries=Retry(total=2, backoff_factor=1, status_forcelist=[ 500, 502, 503, 504, 521])))
r = s.get('http://httpstat.us/500')
r2 = s.post('http://httpstat.us/500')
```

So, the `.get()` requests do retry and the `.post()` ones do not.

What's wrong?

Comment: Is it supposed to work like you expect? `GET` requests won't harm data, but multiple `POST` might. I haven't read through the requests API documentation, but it sounds reasonable if this is by design.

Answer (score 49):

In urllib3 `POST` is not allowed as a retried method by default (since it can cause multiple inserts). You can force it though:

```
Retry(total=3, allowed_methods=frozenset(['GET', 'POST']))
```

See https://urllib3.readthedocs.io/en/latest/reference/urllib3.util.html#urllib3.util.retry.Retry

Comment: Could you explain the logic behind using `frozenset` in this snippet, please?

Comment: @AmirAfianian Check out linked documentation for Retry. The reason is to be type-consistent with default value of `allowed_methods=frozenset({'DELETE', 'GET', 'HEAD', 'OPTIONS', 'PUT', 'TRACE'})`

Comment: Note that if you want to retry "POST" but also keep all of the default methods you can do `allowed_methods=frozenset([*list(Retry.DEFAULT_ALLOWED_METHODS), 'POST'])`

Answer (score 4):

You can use tenacity.

doc: https://tenacity.readthedocs.io/en/latest/

And you can log before or after

```
pip install tenacity
```

```
import logging

logging.basicConfig(stream=sys.stderr, level=logging.DEBUG)

logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)

@retry(stop=stop_after_attempt(3), before=before_log(logger, logging.DEBUG))
def post_something():
    # post
    raise MyException("Fail")
```